# Live updating ajax charts

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, charts, live

I have a website which serves around 20 - 50 widgets per second and I wanted to create a chart that automatically gets data from the server and then updates the chart and I want the chart to run from right to left as more data is added and remove the old values and add the new values. I would like a javascript and php solution.

I have tried google and cannot find any solutions for this and I found a tutorial once but now I have lost that link :( So any kind of help in form of a link, piece of code or what to look for will help.

One thing that I wanted was having the widget start with a delay of fetch data but start displaying the data after 5 seconds of the intial fetch and then fetch data every 2 seconds, however load data second by second. This would ease the load on the server while also generating smooth graphs.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated....

Something Like this for php
http://support.nevron.com/KB/a175/implement-real-time-chart-in-aspnet-application-using-ajax.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you just need two functions running at different intervals that have access to the same variable where all the data will be stored

```
function runChart() {
  var dataObject = [];

  fetchFromServer = function() {
    //Make your Ajax call here
    //and then update 'dataObject'
  }

  //set fetchFromServer to fire every 5 seconds
  setInterval( function () { fetchFromServer() }, 5000 ); 

  loadToChart = function() {
    //In here keep track of what was the last data you added to the chart
    //pull data-points from 'dataObject' 
    //and display the next data-point on the graph
  }
  //set loadToChart to fire every second
  setInterval( function () { loadToChart() } ,1000); 
}
```

Comment: hmmmm....very nice solution...1 up for that (cant need 15 rep haha), but I cant find any good charting libraries which I use along with this function....Can you please suggest that as well and I will go ahead and accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Up now since just got 24 rep...still waiting for reply

Comment: These are the two most robust charting library's that I know of http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ and http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Comment: I apologize in advance if I am asking for too much but how would I implement one of those charts in your given solution...Thanks

Comment: http://support.nevron.com/KB/a175/implement-real-time-chart-in-aspnet-application-using-ajax.aspx something like this but in php and javascript or php and flash.

Comment: Why don't you just follow that tutorial, I'm not going to write all the code for you..

Comment: No, I am just asking for any other charting libraries like that. I am definitely not gonna make you write that code for me. Btw, how much would you charge anyways if you were to write something like that in js/php?